# Trigger tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Can we edit the "magic" trigger tables in SQL Server (which are accesible in the scope of a trigger) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't edit the "magic tables" directly.

> You cannot directly modify the data in
>   the tables or perform data definition
>   language (DDL) operations on the
>   tables, such as CREATE INDEX. Source
>   BOL: [Using the inserted and deleted
>   Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28SQL.90%29.aspx)